# Looking If I can add my own xustom fonts in my code editor in Xcode

Tags: xcode

I wanted to ask If anyone knew If I could add custom fonts to my Xcode editor as I am programming. I couldn't find anything on the Internet so I thought I'd reach out here.

And this font is simply for my editor and not any of my apps.

Comment: Add the font to your mac's fonts using Font Book and then select it in Xcode's themes settings